# Не слышно звук фильма во время стрима

Tags: discord

При демонстрации экрана не слышу фильм, в то время как мой собеседник его слышит.
Можно ли исправить эту проблему?
Учитывая, что я нахожусь в наушниках.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы стримить со звуком, нужно выбрать именно окно приложения, с которого нужно транслировать звук

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте настройки Микрофона и вывода в Discord.

Так же вам следует убедиться что стерео микшер настроен должным образом.

Если транслирует экран ваш собеседник, то у него должен быть включён стерео микшер.